# How to solve the problem that multithreaded drawing is not smooth?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I wrote a data acquisition program with Qt. I collect data using the child threads of the dual cache region written by `QSemphore`.

```
void QThreadShow::run() {
    m_stop=false; // when start thread,m_stop=false

    int n=fullBufs.available();
    if (n>0)
        fullBufs.acquire(n); 

    while (!m_stop) {
        fullBufs.acquire(); // wait fo full buffer
        QVector<double> dataPackage(BufferSize); 
        double seq=bufNo;
        if (curBuf==1) 
            for (int i=0;i<BufferSize;i++){
                dataPackage[i]=buffer2[i]; // copy data from  full buffer
            } 
        else
            for (int i=0;i<BufferSize;i++){
                dataPackage[i]=buffer1[i];
            }

        for (int k=0;k<BufferSize;k++) {
            vectorQpointFbufferData[k]=QPointF(x,dataPackage[k]);
        }
        emptyBufs.release(); // release a buffer
        QVariant variantBufferData;  
        variantBufferData.setValue(vectorQpointFbufferData);
        emit newValue(variantBufferData,seq); // send data to main thread
    }
    quit();
}
```

When a cache of sub-threads has collected 500 data, the data is input into a `QVector` and sent to the main thread and is directly assigned to a lineseries in qchartview every 20ms for drawing. I use `QtChart` to chart the data.

```
void MainWindow::onthreadB_newValue(QVariant bufferData, double bufNo) {
    // Analysis of QVariant data
    CH1.hardSoftDataPointPackage = bufferData.value<QVector<QPointF>>();
    if (ui->CH1_Source->currentIndex()==0) {
        for (int p = 0;p<CH1.hardSoftDataPointPackage.size();p++) {
            series_CH3->append(CH1.hardSoftDataPointPackage[p]);
        }        
    }
}
```

There is a timer in the main thread.The interval is 20ms and there is a double time (time = time +1), which controls the X-axis.

```
void MainWindow::drawAxis(double time) {
    // dynamic draw x axis
    if (time<100) {
        axisX->setRange(0, TimeBase/(1000/FrameRate) * 10);    
        // FrameRate=50
    } else {
        axisX->setRange(time-TimeBase/(1000/FrameRate) * 10, time);
    }
}
```

But when I run my program, there is a problem that every time the subthread sends data to the main thread, the main thread gets stuck for a few seconds and the plot also gets stuck for a few seconds. I added a curve in the main thread getting data from the main thread, and found that both two curves will be stuck at the same time. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Besides, I want the main thread to draw the data from the child thread evenly within 20ms, instead of drawing all the points at once.

Answer (score 2):

Your main thread stucks because you copy (add to series) a lot of data at one time. Instead this you can collect all your data inside your thread instance without emitting a signal. And from main thread just take little pieces of collected data every 20 ms.

Something like this:

```
while(!m_stop)
{
   ...
   //QVariant variantBufferData;  
   //variantBufferData.setValue(vectorQpointFbufferData);
   //emit newValue(variantBufferData,seq);//send data to main thread

   //instead this just store in internal buffer
   m_mutex.lock();
   m_internalBuffer.append(vectorQpointFbufferData);
   m_mutex.unlock();
}
```

Read method

```
QVector<QPointF> QThreadShow::takeDataPiece()
{
    int n = 4;
    QVector<QPointF> piece;
    piece.reserve(n);
    m_mutex.lock();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
         QPointF point = m_internalBuffer.takeFirst();
         piece.append(point);
    }
    m_mutex.unlock();
    return piece;
}
```

And in Main thread read in timeout slot

```
void MainWindow::OnDrawTimer()
{
     QVector<QPointF> piece = m_childThread.takeDataPiece();
     //add to series
     ...
     //drawAxis
     ...
}
```